# What must I do to allow to click on markable zone of FHS form on BS2000 using 9750 emulation?

Tags: bs2000, log-te

In year 2005, I used LOG-TE 9750 to access BS2000 forms developped using FHS on UTM application.

As I remember, I worked on an application where clicking on some protected fields was possible.

Knowing that clicking is not possible on old 9750 terminals, how clicking using LOGT-TE 9750 emulation is possible ?